# How to convert timestamp in ms to YY-MM-DD format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have the following dataframe db_rena:

```
        dep_date             arr_date
0   2020-01-01 17:57:00   2020-01-01 20:58:00
1   2020-01-01 14:01:00   2020-01-01 20:11:00
2   2020-01-01 21:30:00   2020-01-02 01:20:00
```

And  I want to convert it to the YY-MM-DD format, so it would look like this:

```
    dep_date       arr_date
0   2020-01-01    2020-01-01  
1   2020-01-01    2020-01-01 
2   2020-01-01    2020-01-02
```

The original format of the data frame db_rena was db, and it looked like this:

```
    dep_date         arr_date
0   1.577901e+12    1.577912e+12
1   1.577887e+12    1.577909e+12
```

And it was in Float64 format. I used the following code to convert that to datetime:

```
db_rena['dep_date']=pd.to_datetime(db.dep_date,unit='ms')
db_rena['arr_date']=pd.to_datetime(db.arr_date,unit='ms')
```

But I havent managed to convert it to the format I want. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `db_rena['dep_date']=pd.to_datetime(db.dep_date,unit='ms').dt.date`

Answer (score 0):

Yes Thank you It_is_chris, that def works. The solution is:

```
 db_rena['dep_date']=pd.to_datetime(db.dep_date,unit='ms').dt.date
 db_rena['arr_date']=pd.to_datetime(db.arr_date,unit='ms').dt.date
```

Comment: note that this will leave you with a Series of `date` objects (Python datetime.date class) - which is not a format but a data type btw. If you plan on actively working with the dates (time series analysis e.g.), keep the pandas datetime data type (you can `dt.floor('d')` to set H:M:S zero).